# Retornando NullPointer no controller

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Eu tenho um método no `controller` que tem como função fazer um consulta no meu banco e após me retornar apenas um campo dessa busca, porém estou tomando `nullpointer` no primeiro `for` que estou usando. Gostaria de ajuda nisso.

As constantes são essas:

```
private List<String> listaNomeProjeto;
private List<String> listaNomePerfil;
private List<String> listaNomeJornada;

@RequestMapping(value = REDIRECT_PAGE_CADASTRO, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView viewCadastro(Model model) {

        List<Projeto> listaCompletaProjeto = projetoService.findAll();

        for (Projeto listaProjetos : listaCompletaProjeto) {
            listaNomeProjeto.add(listaProjetos.getProjeto());
        }

        List<Perfil> listaCompletaPerfil = perfilService.findAll();

        for (Perfil listaPerfis : listaCompletaPerfil) {
            listaNomePerfil.add(listaPerfis.getPerfil().toString());
        }

        List<Jornada> listaCompletaJornada = jornadaService.findAll();

        for (Jornada listaJornadas : listaCompletaJornada) {
            listaNomeJornada.add(listaJornadas.getDsJornada().toString());
        }

        usuarioBean = new UsuarioBean(listaNomeProjeto, listaNomePerfil, listaNomeJornada);

        model.addAttribute("usuarioBean", usuarioBean);

        return new ModelAndView(REQUEST_MAPPING_PAGE_CADASTRO);
    }
```

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Copie e cole o `stacktrace` inteiro do erro na sua pergunta, senão fica difícil saber qual o problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não está inicializando suas listas, então no momento que o método `add` é chamado para a variável `listaNomeProjeto`, uma exceção é disparada já que ela é nula. Um modo de corrigir desconsiderando a sua regra de negócio (que não está clara) é o substituir as declarações para o seguinte:

```
private List<String> listaNomeProjeto = new ArrayList<>();
private List<String> listaNomePerfil = new ArrayList<>();
private List<String> listaNomeJornada = new ArrayList<>();
```

Talvez você deva considerar a criação das variáveis dentro do seu método:

```
@RequestMapping(value = REDIRECT_PAGE_CADASTRO, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView viewCadastro(Model model) {
  List<Projeto> listaCompletaProjeto = projetoService.findAll();
  List<String> listaNomeProjeto = new ArrayList<>();
  List<String> listaNomePerfil = new ArrayList<>();
  List<String> listaNomeJornada = new ArrayList<>();
  ...
}
```